# Is there a way to get the country name from where user is accessing the web site?

Tags: java

I have a requirement wher i need to store the country of the user in the database. I can keep a check box or combo box for that but is there any way to fetch the country info without the user having to enter it ?? Is there a way to get the country name from where user is accessing the web site?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to to do this, but some work is required on your part.  When a user accesses your website, you can get his/her IP address using:

```
String ip = (request.getHeader("X_FORWARDED_FOR") == null ? request.getRemoteAddr() : request.getHeader("X_FORWARDED_FOR"));
```

Then you can convert this ip address into its binary form:

```
long binIp = ipToLong(ip);
```

with `ipToLong` function being something like this:

```
public long ipToLong(String addr) {
    String[] addrArray = addr.split("\\.");

    return Long.parseLong(addrArray[0]) << 24 +
           Long.parseLong(addrArray[1]) << 16 +
           Long.parseLong(addrArray[2]) << 8 +
           Long.parseLong(addrArray[3]);

}
```

And finally use IP address database to look up which country this value belongs to.  There are several providers.  We get ours from [software77](http://software77.net/geo-ip/) - it's free - and store in a local database, updating local DB once a month.

A few notes:

1. Sometimes the address will not be set, so you'll need to have some reasonable defaults.
2. Sometimes the address will be spoofed and hence not represent a real IP address (format-wise), so you'll need to have reasonable exception handling.
3. Sometimes the address will be from a reserved range (e.g. 192.168/16), so, again, you'll need to have some reasonable defaults.

Comment: thanks a lot ... i ll try it and let you know if there is further queries . thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

that's the IP Locator service. See the sample code and the application @ `http://www.geobytes.com/iplocator.htm` The source is in PHP though, you can try to write it in java.